# Silverlight User Control Position

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, web-parts, translation

I have a User control inside a web part that is being used to perform an query. The user control can grow in height to a certain point depending on how many results there is.
This can cause the Header of the user control to be pushed outside the view-able area.

I want to get the position of the user control and when the Y coord is negative to move the user control so that the Y coord is a positive value.

I am using the code from this post to get the user control's position:
[Determine a UIElement's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114322/translating-x-y-coordinate?answertab=active#tab-top)

But now that I have the position I can't figure out how to move the user control.
I tried using `userControl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 15.0)`
but it had no effect.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:   XAML Extract Added

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gazetteer.Search" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="336" d:DesignWidth="342" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFE2E2E2" MinHeight="80" MinWidth="280">

    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton x:Name="townlandRB" Margin="5" Checked="radioBtnCheck"
            GroupName="Search Type" Content="Townland" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="sitecodeRB" Margin="5" Checked="radioBtnCheck"
            GroupName="Search Type" Content="Site Code" />
        </StackPanel>            
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show your XAML? The positioning depends on the container type your User control is within. Otherwise you could use a TranslateTranform to move it.

Comment: Thanks HiTech MAgic, I've used TranslateTransform and it is working correctly now!

Comment: Useful, but I meant the Xaml of the page that contains your user control :)

Comment: Well you see that's part of the problem. The compiled XAP from this user control is uploaded into a SharePoint site so I don't have direct access to the page where it is stored.
But thanks to your comment, what I did was get the parent of the User Control and add a TranslateTransform to the Parent's RenderTransform in the code behind.  I then just set the Y coord of the TranslateTransform which moves the whole User control.

Comment: +1 for providing XAML. Always helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning depends on the container type your User control is within. Canvas.TopProperty does nothing unless the parent is actually a Canvas.

Use a TranslateTransform to move the object instead.